# Nifi using Docker - Unable to obtain listing of buckets: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, apache-nifi

I am trying to use Nifi with Docker but I am stuck in this error and cannot solve it.

I am configuring Metabase, MySQL, Nifi and Nifi-registry in the same network. The docker-compose.yml is going up normally, but when I try to connect the Nifi with a bucket in Nifi-registry I keep getting this error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VeiQ.png)

My OS: Ubuntu 20.04.

I saw the documentation and it talks only about local installation, configuring the Nifi files.

I followed [this](https://youtu.be/gf9_zGjNK3A) video.

This is my docker-compose file:

```
  version: "3"

services:   db:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql_57
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"   metabase:
    image: metabase/metabase
    container_name: metabase
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - data:/metabase   nifi:
    image: apache/nifi:latest
    container_name: nifi
    ports:
      - "8443:8443"
    cpus: 2
    mem_limit: 2G
    mem_reservation: 2G
    environment:
      - SINGLE_USER_CREDENTIALS_USERNAME=myusername
      - SINGLE_USER_CREDENTIALS_PASSWORD=mypassword
      - NIFI_SENSITIVE_PROPS_KEY=mykey
    volumes:
      - nifi_content_repository:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/content_repository
      - nifi_database_repository:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/database_repository
      - nifi_flowfile_repository:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/flowfile_repository
      - nifi_provenance_repository:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/provenance_repository
      - nifi_state:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/state
      - nifi_logs:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs
      - nifi_data:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/data
      - nifi_conf:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf
      - type: bind
        source: ./drivers
        target: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/drivers
    networks:
      - rede_projeto

  nifi-registry:
    image: apache/nifi-registry:latest
    container_name: nifi-registry
    ports:
      - "18080:18080"
    cpus: 1
    mem_limit: 1G
    mem_reservation: 1G
    networks:
      - rede_projeto 


volumes:   nifi_content_repository:
    driver: local   nifi_database_repository:
    driver: local   nifi_flowfile_repository:
    driver: local   nifi_provenance_repository:
    driver: local   nifi_conf:
    driver: local   nifi_state:
    driver: local   nifi_logs:
    driver: local   nifi_data:
    driver: local   nifi_drivers:
    driver: local   data:
    driver: local


networks:   rede_projeto:
    external: true
```